The upload field is cleared in a relationship with subfields in old post after failed validation in Laravel backpack
I have two models - Ticket and Document. The relationship is configured as follows:
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
    }
}

class Document extends Model
{
    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
    }
}

A ticket may have many documents. In crud the createOperation/updateOperation looks like this:
[
    'tab'   => trans($this->trans_prefix . 'tabs.main'),
    'name'  => 'documents',
    'type'  => 'relationship',
    'label' => trans($this->trans_prefix_relationship . 'documents'),
    'subfields'   => [
        /* other fields */
        [
            'name'      => 'path',
            'label'     => 'Documents',
            'type'      => 'upload',
            'withFiles' => [
                'path' => self::STORAGE_PATH,
                'fileNamer' => function($file, $uploader) {
                    return md5($file . date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) . Str::random(10);
                }
            ]
        ],
     ]
]

I tried to set the same validation rules for the path field as for the other subfields from this relationship
'documents.*.path' => [
    'required',
    'file'
],

If the ticket did not have documents and we add a new one, everything works correctly. Problems begin if the ticket already had a document and we upload a new one. If the path field in the new record is empty, the validation will work as expected and the page will reload, but similar path fields in previously loaded document records will be cleared. I'm not sure if this is normal behavior for an upload field in a backpack. Is it possible to somehow bypass this behavior so that when validation is triggered, the upload fields (other subfields work correctly) in loaded document records are not cleared?
